# How to calculate cumulative sum and stop after it exceeds a pre-defined integer in AWK?

Tags: linux, awk, sum

I have a unsorted list of integers; say

```
1
2
3
3
4
5
5
2
```

I want to sort the list, and then calculate cumulative sum until the sum reaches a pre-defined integer; say 17. After stopping, it should print the last integer which added up to exceed the pre-defined integer. See example

My sorted list will be:

```
5
5
4
3
3
2
2
1
```

5+5+4+3=17, so the cumulative sum will stop here and will print the last integer which is '3'

I tried this with no luck :(

```
 awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum= sum+$0; if (sum >= '$pre-defined_integer') print $0}
```

Comment: The script is fine, you are only failing in using the var. Just say `-v var="$pre_defined_integer" '{... if (sum >= var) print }'`

Comment: there is still the sort problem that is not "simple" use of variable in this case if a piped sort is not used in command line

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat add.txt
5
5
4
3
3
2
2
1

$ pre_defined_integer=17

$ awk -v pdi=$pre_defined_integer '{sum += $0; if (sum >= pdi) {print; exit}}' add.txt
3
```

More or less you had it. For correctness I think you were just missing the `exit` so that you didn't keep printing after reaching the pre-defined limit.

But other things to note:

- Most importantly, the best way to use variables from the shell is to pass them to awk via the `-v` option.

And a few small things:

- The `BEGIN` block isn't really necessary since awk initializes variables to zero.
- `x += y` can be used in place of `x = x + y`
- `print $0` can simply be written as `print`

Comment: same concept (still not sorted as OP ask) so not another reply `awk -v pdi=${pre_defined_integer} '(sum+=$1) >= pdi {print;exit}' add.txt`

Comment: `pre_defined_integer=17
    awk -v pdi=${pre_defined_integer} '{vs[NR] = $1}
       END{ asort(vs,ss)
            for( i=1; i<=NR && ( (Sum+=vs[ss[i]]) <= pdi);)i++
            print vs[ss[i]]
          }' addt.txt `

only work with gnu awk due to sorti function not in posix awk